# Swapping the Content of Columns with jQuery on Small Screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an alternating two-column layout made with Twitter Bootstrap 3.

First row has an image on the left and text on the right. Second row has text on the left and an image on the right. And so on.

What I would like to do is on smaller screens (less than 768px) where it turns into a single-column layout have the rows where the image is on the right swap the content of the two columns so the image is displayed on top.

The rows with the image on the right have the class of `even`.

Here is the html of an `even` row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left evenleft">
        text
    </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 right evenright">
        image
    </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

Here is the jQuery I am trying to use:

```
function swap() {
    $('.even').each(function () {
        var left, right;
        left = $(this).find('.evenleft').html();
        right = $(this).find('.evenright').html();
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(this).find('.evenleft').html(right);
            $(this).find('.evenright').html(left);
        } else {
            $(this).find('.evenleft').html(left);
            $(this).find('.evenright').html(right);
        }
    });
}
$(function () {
    swap();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    swap();
});
```

It works perfectly when you start the page already re-sized. But when re-size the browser it doesn't work.

I am kind of lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.col-sm-pull-6` and `.col-sm-push-6`:

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        image
    </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        text
    </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
</div> <!-- end row -->`

http://plnkr.co/edit/0f1Id9VYZlRel66OeKni?p=preview

Comment: Wow! Never noticed those classes before! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could place the image first and float it right. I'd imagine you wouldn't need JS at all fot this.